Instances cannot be resolved error gives no trace
I'm getting the error System.ObjectDisposedException: Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.
To investigate this I added a diagnostic tracer. I'm now getting traces in my logs, but all traces indicate the operation succeeded. I do not appear to be a getting a trace with the above error.
Should this type of error have a corresponding trace?

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

How can I write a minimal reproducible example if I don't know what is causing the error? I can't reproduce this locally, only when deployed. I'm just looking for information on how tracing works.
